# I can't pinpoint why memory gets corrupted while working with Recursive Tagged Union in Zig

Tags: enums, unions, recursive-datastructures, zig

I am working on a small feature-incomplete Lisp interpreter to learn a bit of Zig. My inspiration is this https://norvig.com/lispy.html, this might not be the most idiomatic way of implementing that in C/Zig but nevertheless quite small and simple which is what I am looking for. I am now on the stage of representing AST via tagged union. However, I can't understand the reason why the code below seem to end me up in a corrupted/overwritten memory state.

```
const std = @import("std");
// const test_string = "(begin (define r 10) (* pi (* r r)))";
const shorter_test_string = "(begin (define r 10))";
const Allocator = std.mem.Allocator;

const Tag = enum { String, Number, Bool, Symbol };
const Type = union(Tag) { String: std.ArrayList(u8), Number: i64, Bool: bool, Symbol: []const u8 };
const TokenType = enum { Expr, Single };
const Token = union(TokenType) {
    Expr: *std.ArrayList(*Token),
    Single: *Type,
};

pub fn finalizeWord(string_collector: *std.ArrayList(u8), outer_list: *std.ArrayList(std.ArrayList(u8))) !void {
    if (!std.mem.eql(u8, string_collector.items, "")) {
        try outer_list.append(try string_collector.clone());
        string_collector.clearRetainingCapacity();
    }
}

// TODO: I commented out all the deallocations for debugging purposes, will add them later
pub fn tokenize(alloca: *Allocator, parsed_input: *std.ArrayList(std.ArrayList(u8))) !*Token {
    var token: std.ArrayList(u8) = parsed_input.orderedRemove(0);
    if (std.mem.eql(u8, token.items, "(")) {
        std.debug.print("Open bracket encountered \n", .{});
        // defer token.deinit();
        var list = std.ArrayList(*Token).init(alloca.*);
        var local_token = try moveToHeap(alloca, Token{ .Expr = &list });
        while (!std.mem.eql(u8, parsed_input.items[0].items, ")")) {
            std.debug.print("While loop iteration \n", .{});
            var item_to_add = try tokenize(alloca, parsed_input);
            try list.append(item_to_add);
        }
        _ = parsed_input.orderedRemove(0);
        // defer closing_bracket.deinit();
        return local_token;
    } else if (std.mem.eql(u8, token.items, ")")) {
        // TODO: This is definitely not unreachable but a Syntax Error
        unreachable;
    } else {
        var item = try moveToHeap(alloca, Token{ .Single = try atomize(alloca, token) });
        std.debug.print("Single item encountered: {s} \n", .{item.*.Single.*.String.items});
        return item;
    }
}

pub fn atomize(alloca: *Allocator, item: std.ArrayList(u8)) !*Type {
    return try moveToHeap(alloca, Type{ .String = try item.clone() });
}

pub fn parse(alloca: *Allocator, input_string: []const u8) !std.ArrayList(std.ArrayList(u8)) {
    var outer_list = std.ArrayList(std.ArrayList(u8)).init(alloca.*);
    var string_collector = std.ArrayList(u8).init(alloca.*);
    defer string_collector.deinit();
    for (input_string) |character| {
        if (character == '(') {
            try finalizeWord(&string_collector, &outer_list);
            var opening_bracket = std.ArrayList(u8).init(alloca.*);
            try opening_bracket.append('(');
            try outer_list.append(opening_bracket);

            continue;
        } else if (character == ')') {
            try finalizeWord(&string_collector, &outer_list);
            var closing_bracket = std.ArrayList(u8).init(alloca.*);
            try closing_bracket.append(')');
            try outer_list.append(closing_bracket);

            continue;
        } else if (character == ' ') {
            try finalizeWord(&string_collector, &outer_list);
        } else {
            try string_collector.append(character);
        }
    }
    return outer_list;
}

pub fn moveToHeap(allocator: *Allocator, value: anytype) !*@TypeOf(value) {
    const T = @TypeOf(value);
    std.debug.assert(@typeInfo(T) != .Pointer);
    const ptr = try allocator.create(T);
    ptr.* = value;
    return ptr;
}

pub fn print_tokens(token: *Token) void {
    switch (token.*) {
        .Expr => |expr| {
            // TODO: deallocations should happen in separate functions
            // defer expr.deinit();
            std.debug.print("Processing Expression \n", .{});
            for (expr.items) |t| {
                print_tokens(t);
            }
        },
        .Single => |item| {
            // TODO: deallocations should happen in separate functions
            // defer item.*.String.deinit();
            std.debug.print("Processing Token: {s}\n", .{item.*.String.items});
        },
    }
}

pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    defer {
        _ = gpa.deinit();
    }
    var allocator = gpa.allocator();
    var parsed_string = try parse(&allocator, shorter_test_string);
    defer parsed_string.deinit();
    defer {
        for (parsed_string.items) |item| {
            item.deinit();
        }
    }
    var tokens = try tokenize(&allocator, &parsed_string);
    print_tokens(tokens); // SEGFAULT happens here
}
```

The particular part I am struggling with are functions `tokenize` and `print_tokens`. If you run the code in `main` you get the SEGFAULTS while printing tokens, which seems to occur because once you exit `tokenize` function the memory for some of the nested `Expr` get corrupted/overwritten. I have a gut feeling that this form of representation

```
const Tag = enum { String, Number, Bool, Symbol };
const Type = union(Tag) { String: std.ArrayList(u8), Number: i64, Bool: bool, Symbol: []const u8 };
const TokenType = enum { Expr, Single };
const Token = union(TokenType) {
    Expr: *std.ArrayList(*Token),
    Single: *Type,
};
```

might have some inherent design problems but at this point I am wondering what might be the actual cause for memory overwriting since everything is manually placed on Heap.

I tried debugging with LLDB and it seems like even putting `print` or making a heap allocation here

```
_ = parsed_input.orderedRemove(0);
std.debug.print("Sample print", .{});
// defer closing_bracket.deinit();
return local_token;
```

overwrites the inner `Expr` in `local_token.*.Expr.*.items[1]`. As I mentioned previously I am now more interested in why the memory problems occur then in the final Lisp interpreter implementation :)

**EDIT:**

It seems like Zig type system kind of tricked me into thinking it was doing more magic than I thought. `std.ArrayList` is a struct with items allocated on the heap and the problem was that I stored a pointer to a local stack allocated struct `list` in a heap allocated union `local_token`

One alternative solution, aside from the one suggested in comments, I found is storing `std.ArrayList(*Token)` in an `Expr`, making it de-facto an owner of the struct representing ArrayList.

```
const Token = union(TokenType) {
    Expr: std.ArrayList(*Token),
    Single: Type,
};
```

and the function `tokenize`:

```
// TODO: I commented out all the deallocations for debugging purposes, will add them later
pub fn tokenize(alloca: *Allocator, parsed_input: *std.ArrayList(std.ArrayList(u8))) !*Token {
    var token: std.ArrayList(u8) = parsed_input.orderedRemove(0);
    if (std.mem.eql(u8, token.items, "(")) {
        std.debug.print("Open bracket encountered \n", .{});
        // defer token.deinit();
        var local_token = try moveToHeap(alloca, Token{ .Expr = std.ArrayList(*Token).init(alloca.*) });
        while (!std.mem.eql(u8, parsed_input.items[0].items, ")")) {
            std.debug.print("While loop iteration \n", .{});
            var item_to_add = try tokenize(alloca, parsed_input);
            try local_token.*.Expr.append(item_to_add);
        }
        _ = parsed_input.orderedRemove(0);
        // defer closing_bracket.deinit();
        return local_token;
    } else if (std.mem.eql(u8, token.items, ")")) {
        // TODO: This is definitely not unreachable but a Syntax Error
        unreachable;
    } else {
        var item = try moveToHeap(alloca, Token{ .Single = try atomize(token) });
        std.debug.print("Single item encountered: {s} \n", .{item.*.Single.String.items});
        return item;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Apparently, I don't need additional heap allocations altogether. I was worried that I will end up with recursive data structures that aren't sized properly but using ArrayList with a `Token` stored in it already gives it the correct layout, hence this code would be more optimal:

```
const Token = union(TokenType) {
    Expr: std.ArrayList(Token),
    Single: Type,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in how you create the expression list in `tokenize`:

```
var list = std.ArrayList(*Token).init(alloca.*);
var local_token = try moveToHeap(alloca, Token{ .Expr = &list });
```

You store a pointer to `list`, but it lives on the function's stack. Once `tokenize` exits, the pointer becomes invalid. Simply create the list with the allocator. For example:

```
var list = try alloca.create(std.ArrayList(*Token));
list.* = std.ArrayList(*Token).init(alloca.*);
var local_token = try moveToHeap(alloca, Token{ .Expr = list });
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work, though  it was a little confusing. If I understood correctly `std.ArrayList(*Token).init(alloca.*);` basically gives you a stack allocated struct with items allocated on heap inside of it, thus I was making a stack allocated variable which stores the struct with heap allocated values and storing a pointer to that variable in a different struct would absolutely invalidate the pointer afterwards

Comment: `init` returns a value that is written to the function stack. Conceptually, it's no different than doing `var a: i32 = 0`.